# What is Service Account in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, security, tfs

I am very new in TFS 2010. I have setup my PC as server. I need to connect the client machine with this server. I have added a Service Account in TFS console. The client machine are connected with this account.

Now, my question is that, is the Service Account is intended to connect the client with server?

Can anyone explain me the purpose of this account?

Also I need to know, how to find(or setup) the TFS admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you referring to the "TFSSERVICE" service account from the installation guide?  That account is used to run various services related to TFS, for example the TFS Task Scheduler.  It should have the minimum privileges possible on the machine.

The client should not connect to the server with a service account, they should be using their own account which you grant access to the relevant repositories in TFS.  If you connect all clients with the service account, how will you know who checked in each changeset?

You might find the installation guide of use which can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24337).  See section entitled "Accounts Required for Installation of Team Foundation Components".

If you are using a **domain**, you should be able to follow the instructions in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for how permissions work in TFS.  You can allocate permissions to resources from the Team Explorer pane within Visual Studio.

If you're using TFS in a **workgroup** then it's a little different as you need to set up local accounts for your users.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507.aspx).

Comment: Open TFS admin console, under Application Tier Summary, Service Account. This is the account. Can you tell me how can client connect and how to grant access to the repository? I am very new?

Comment: Are your machines part of a domain?

Comment: OK, but are they members of a Windows domain using Active Directory?  Or do they just happen to coexist on the same LAN?

Comment: No, they are only connected in the same LAN.

Comment: In which case, you should follow the instructions in my final link.  Microsoft says that Active Directory is recommended, but it is possible with a workgroup.  However you have to shadow each client account onto the server for a seamless experience and grant them access in the correct places.